# GPG error: http://www.geekconnection.org karmic/ InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)

Tags: virtualbox, gnupg

```
E: GPG error: http://www.geekconnection.org karmic/ InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
```

"*I am constantly encountering above error while updating. Please help me to solve this problem.*"

Answer (score 0):

If you visit their site [here](http://www.geekconnection.org/) you will see that the site is no longer functioning - it's a dead site. Remove the PPA associated with this site and this error will also go away.

Comment: how to search for the associated PPA's?

Comment: @thyagarajulu I use Lubuntu so it's probably a little different. It'll be under Software Sources or something similar. Look for updates or type software into the search and it should find it for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now I am facing the following problem:

Comment: W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/ saucy/contrib amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/download.virtualbox.org_virtualbox_debian_dists_saucy_contrib_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/ saucy/contrib i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/download.virtualbox.org_virtualbox_debian_dists_saucy_contrib_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems